# Python Class & Class Instantiation shows a very weird behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently writing an API-Connector for Snapchat Ads. I wrote a class. However, while testing I am seeing an unusual behavior. The code below illustrates the behavior. Using Version 3.7

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import datetime as dt

class SnapchatAPI(object):   
    def __int__(self, client_id, client_secret, org_id):
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.org_id = org_id
```

For example, the above is the declaration of the class. when I run it and try to instantiate it without parameters. It still works.[It should not. But it does]. I can't figure out why `SnapchatAPI()` **works without raising and Error**?

```
extractor = SnapchatAPI()
```

However, while trying to figure out I fell back to simple class like the following to check the behavior

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, address):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.address = address
```

And when I try to instantiate it without parameters. It raises an error. Which is what I expected

```
john_doe = Person()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'firstname', 'lastname', and 'address'
```

Can't figure out why!

Comment: `__int__` is not how you spell `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the typo in my source code. The problem was because of the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you posted is exactly whats in your script its a simple typo. You have defined `__int__` instead of `__init__`. When a class is not given an `__init__()` method it inherits `__init__` from `object()` I believe. This takes no parameters, hence why it works without you explicitly defining an `__init__` method.